# how to get all running SQL job's packages using C#?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ssis

I want to make desktop application that read all working jobs on SQL management studio and return them in a tree view .. all what i need is to know away or function that reads all working jobs and return back packages of each job

Answer (score 0):

MSDN is often a good resource for questions like yours. Here is the method to enumerate the SQL jobs on a given SQL server. [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms210360.aspx) is the example given for use in a C# context. CHEERS!